# In ZF, can it be proven that a non-trivial real vector space has a non-zero linear functional?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've been through a number of older similar threads and it does not seem clear that this question is answered anywhere. I know this can be proven without the full strength of the Axiom of Choice but can it be proven in ZF with no additional axioms?

Comment: I don't think so. Specifically I believe that it's consistent with ZF that $\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} / \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$ has trivial dual, but I don't know a proof.

Comment: No, your statement is equivalent to Hahn-Banach over ZF, as proved [in this paper](https://ems.press/journals/zaa/articles/10911)

Comment: Can you make the body of the question actually contain a question? While you're at it, the functional analysis tag suggests you're interested in continuous functionals, but you only said "real" and not normed, Banach, topological, or otherwise.